# Create dynamic relationship between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a model called `changes` and I defined it as

```
create_table :ticket_changes do |t|
  t.string :item
  t.belongs_to :old_state
  t.belongs_to :new_state
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

where `:item` is either `Status`, `Type` or `Priority`
the `old_states` and `new_states` will be id's of records on the tables outlined in the `item` field.

When building the model `changes.rb` I would normally write a line

```
    belongs_to :old_state, :class_name => 'TABLENAME'
    belongs_to :new_state, :class_name => 'TABLENAME'
```

but the problem is that table name always changes. Any advice so I can call the `status.name` such as `@change.old_state.name` and it knows to look at the status table because the item of that record (@change) is `Status`?

Comment: i think you should make change a polymorphic relations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: I would like to second polymorphism in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [polymorphic associations,](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) this is pretty easy. A polymorphic association essentially allows you to store the `id` of a relation, along with what it's related to. So in this case, you can say that `old_state` and `new_state` may belong to various other models.

Your code will look something like this:

```
# migration
create_table :ticket_changes do |t|
  t.references :old_state, polymorphic: true
  t.references :new_state, polymorphic: true
  t.string :item
  t.timestamps null: false
end
# TicketChanges class
class TicketChange < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :old_state, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :new_state, polymorphic: true
end

#Status
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ticket_changes, as: :old_state
  has_many :ticket_changes, as: :new_state
end

# Type
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ticket_changes, as: :old_state
  has_many :ticket_changes, as: :new_state
end

# Priority
class Priority < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ticket_changes, as: :old_state
  has_many :ticket_changes, as: :new_state
end
```

Rails will basically do exactly what you were planning on, although it will make its own fields for what you wanted to use `t.item` for.

Note that you probably want a custom validation to ensure that `old_state` and `new_state` are the same type of model. Rails stores the model of each polymorphic field separately, making it possible for `old_state` to be a `Status` while `new_state` is a `Type`.

Comment: Yea, I got this to work perfectly. the only problem is in the view. I can't get the `status.name` where `name` is an attribute of the status. I tried calling it as `@change.old_state.name` and get an error `uninitialized constant Status`

Comment: Could I get more details about where this error is coming from? Can you call just `@change.old_state` without it throwing an error? Note: you also need to make sure to put the `has_many` lines in their respective model files (`app/models/status.rb` for `Status`).

Comment: throws the same error. I have all the models like you outlined as well as `ticket.rb` has `has_many :ticket_changes`

Comment: `<%= change.user.full_name %> changed the <%= change.old_state_type %>` works but....  `<%= change.user.full_name %> changed the <%= change.old_state_type %> from <%= change.old_state %> to <%= change.new_state %>` fails

Comment: In `ticket.rb`, are you just typing `has_many :ticket_changes` or are you typing `has_many :ticket_changes, as: :old_state` and `has_many :ticket_changes, as: :new_state`? The second form is needed to get proper functionality for `Ticket`. Also, if you could post a stack trace, that would be helpful.

Comment: I tried that but then `@ticket_changes` is null when looking for it in the controller as `@ticket_changes = @ticket.ticket_changes`

Comment: You need a separate relation to `Ticket` on the `TicketChanges` model. Put `belongs_to :ticket` inside of `app/model/ticket_change.rb` and add the relevant DB field.

Comment: belongs_to was on `ticket_change.rb` and here is ticketchages schema: `create_table "ticket_changes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",        limit: 4
    t.integer  "old_state_id",   limit: 4
    t.string   "old_state_type", limit: 255
    t.integer  "new_state_id",   limit: 4
    t.string   "new_state_type", limit: 255
    t.integer  "ticket_id",      limit: 4
    t.datetime "change_time"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79456/discussion-between-thesuper-and-cameron-aziz).